# Проверка существования Properties.Settings

Tags: c#, properties

Есть приложение на WinForms, в котором используются настройки Properties.Settings.
При каждом изменении версии настроек нет и требуется выполнить `Properties.Default.Upgrade();`

А как проверить что настроек нет?
Если смотреть само свойство `Properties.Settings.Default` — оно существует.
Есть смотреть `Properties.Settings.Default.Переменная` — оно тоже существует.
А по факту на новой версии даже папки с настройками нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дело в том, что при отсутствии пользовательских настроек, подтягиваются настройки по умолчанию, поэтому не остается ничего кроме как завести в настройках еще один элемент `bool`-типа со значением `true` по умолчанию, например `UpgradeRequired`, и при каждом запуске приложения, проверять его:

```
if (Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired)
{
    Settings.Default.Upgrade();
    Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired = false;
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: Какой симпатичный костыль. Но работает).